# Hide rows in table with vertically merged cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to hide parts of a table in Word which includes vertically and horizontally-merged cells based on user-input.

The table contains of a maximum of 6 "blocks" with the following format:
[image: table format with vertical and horizontal merged cells]

Those "blocks" should be hidden based on user-input (e.g. user selects "2" -> block 1 and 2 should be visible and block 3 to 6 should be hidden).

I tried three approaches:

1. Hide via Rows

```vb
T.Rows(((i - 1) * 6) + j).range.Font.Hidden = True
```

it throws

> error 5991: Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells.

2. Hide via Cells

```vb
T.Cell(((i - 1) * 6) + j, 1).range.Font.Hidden = False
```

Text in the columns is hidden, but not the cell itself, leaving the border and background color.

3. Hide via Bookmarks

I defined in Word the different parts of the table as Bookmark and tried to hide the bookmark:

```vb
Dim curBookmark As Bookmark
curBookmark = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LABEL" & i)
curBookmark.range.Font.Hidden = True
```

This is leaving an empty row with borders visible for each hidden "block"/bookmark.

Comment: I hope I am wrong but I don't think you will be able to hide rows when there is vertical merging, or make them "invisibly thin". You might be able to do some of this by putting "rows 2-5" inside a nested table, but that creates other layout alignment problems. If the table and its blocks are in a fixed format (i.e. the user isn't supposed to be able to change them), I would probably find some way to save the data in the table and reconstruct it from scratch instead of trying to hide/reveal.

Comment: Thanks for your input jonsson. Luckily JohnM provided a solution, which works in my case. The trick is to iterate through the cells and add the "end-row-characters" in each identified row. Once this is applied. It works really well. See below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've solved this is to get a single Range object covering all the Cells in the Table *including* the end-of-row characters and then hide the Range all in one go. This is a Sub you can use, passing in the Table and the first and last rows to hide:

```
Sub HideRows(tbl As Table, rowFrom As Long, rowTo As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rngTo As Long
    For i = 1 To tbl.Range.Cells.Count
        ' get Range for first cell in a row we are interested in
        If tbl.Range.Cells(i).RowIndex = rowFrom And rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = tbl.Range.Cells(i).Range
        End If
        ' get position of end of last cell in a row we are interested in
        If tbl.Range.Cells(i).RowIndex = rowTo Then
            rngTo = tbl.Range.Cells(i).Range.End
        End If
    Next i
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ' if no valid Range then show entire table
        tbl.Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Else
        rng.End = rngTo
        rng.MoveEnd WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1 ' this is the key ... include end of row char
        tbl.Range.Font.Hidden = False
        rng.Font.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can call it like this, for example:

```
HideRows ThisDocument.Tables(1), 4, 8
```

... which will hide rows 4 to 8 and all other rows will be visible. The vertically merged cell(s) will be hidden if they are entirely within the row numbers passed-in to `HideRows`. To show the entire table, pass in two zeros e.g.

```
HideRows ThisDocument.Tables(1), 0, 0
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This works like a charm. Thanks for your explanations, which helped me to understand the gap in my understanding! Did just one little amendment to match my use case, but wow! Great! Thank you, once again.